# What is the best software/package to draw the robot manipulator and indicate DH parameters and different axes?

Tags: robotic-arm, simulation, industrial-robot, dh-parameters, robotc

I'm wondering about good software/package to draw the robot manipulator and indicate DH parameters and different axes?

Any suggestions!

Comment: Is the software supposed to give you just a drawing? I.e., you care about the artistic aspects of the drawing? Or do you expect to have some other software possibly read the drawing and "import" the robot?

Comment: Actually I don't expect to have a plenty of time, so I'm looking the shortest way.

Comment: That does not answer any of my questions. The shortest way may be an extremely ugly drawing on paper and scanning it. You need to specify what you are trying to do with the drawing, otherwise just for the sake of drawing there are many programs, such as [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/).

Comment: Anyway, both options are useful for me, even I prefer the first option, to draw the robot my self. You mean importing a picture of the robot to Solid Work or other package, I don't like this option, but might also be considered.

Answer (score 4):

Use **[RoboAnalyzer](http://www.roboanalyzer.com/)**. It will help you understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Many kinematics software packages let you easily specify the robot dimensions in an xml format.  You describe the translations and rotations between joints in vectors, quaternions, rotation matrices, etc. and not in DH parameters.  For example: [OpenRave XML format](http://openrave.programmingvision.com/wiki/index.php/Format:XML), and [ROS MoveIt! URDF format](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/URDF).